# MongoDB+NodeJS Foreign keys entire document

Tags: node.js, mongodb, foreign-keys, documents

I am new to NodeJS & MongoDB so maybe this question has been already asked but I couldn't a simple answer, so sorry for that if it is the case.

I am working on a schema looking like that :

```
var usersSchema              = new mongoose.Schema({
    profile          : {
        email               : {type: String, default: ''},
        password            : {type: String, default: ''},
        firstName           : {type: String, default: ''},
    },
    friends          : [{
        type                : mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
        ref                 : 'usersSchema'
    }], 
    pets          : [{
        type                : mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
        ref                 : 'petsSchema'
    }],
});
```

1) Is that possible to make a Schema refering to itself ( here user refer to list of friends, who are users also) ? I didn't found any answer against that but better be sure.

2) Actually I am getting a list of ObjectID for pets, but not other attributes such as name, pedigree... etc. Is that possible to load the entire Pets document from the request ?

```
User.findOne({ 'profile.email' :  req.user.profile.email }).populate('Pets').exec(function(err, user){  ....
```

==> This is returning only object Ids for pets.

Thanks a lot for your eventual answers ! 
Have a nice day all !

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you are specifying Schema name in the ref, you need to specify the model name there.

As shown in example on mongoose site

```
 var mongoose = require('mongoose')
, Schema = mongoose.Schema

var personSchema = Schema({
  _id     : Number,
  name    : String,
  age     : Number,
  stories : [{ type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'Story' }]
});

var storySchema = Schema({
  _creator : { type: Number, ref: 'Person' },
  title    : String,
  fans     : [{ type: Number, ref: 'Person' }]
});

var Story  = mongoose.model('Story', storySchema);
var Person = mongoose.model('Person', personSchema);
```

And if you take your schema it will look like below code.

```js
var petSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
 firstName: {
  type: String,
  default: ''
 },
 pedigree: {
  type: String,
  default: ''
 }
});


var usersSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
 profile: {
  email: {
   type: String,
   default: ''
  },
  password: {
   type: String,
   default: ''
  },
  firstName: {
   type: String,
   default: ''
  },
 },

 friends: [{
  type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
  ref: 'User'
 }],

 pets: [{
  type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
  ref: 'Pet'
 }]
});


// we need to create a model to use it
var User = mongoose.model('User', UserSchema);
var Pet = mongoose.model('Pet', petSchema);
```

Comment: Hello thank you for the answer, I changed the schema accordingly. But it seems not to be working. I am always retrieving the Object IDs and not the content of the object. So it looks like I have to select the objects in the Pet table as well selecting with the Object ID key.